# Reactjs, React, styled-components - Does Rebass library object literal based props rerender components unnecessary?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am new to react and wondering using react with REBASS : https://github.com/rebassjs/rebass  for ui component design and responsiveness, but syntax i say bothers me as they are objects created in render function.
Doesn't it will create unnecessary re-renders ?

if not why not. Not able to understand.

`<Box css={**{color:blue}**} width={**[1,1/2,1/4]**} />`

https://github.com/rebassjs/grid

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In my thinking, you want to use the styling is react-app.

if you want make the other styles.css, you have to make it first, and then import the style.

For example, `import ./styles.css` -> this styles.css have to same located your react App. if you wanna change this, you can control by use './', '../'

and then  --> comes from the style.css.
When you want to add the style, you have to use the **"ClassName"**

The other ways find this~! [react_Style ways](https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822)

Have a good day~!

[enter link description here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html)

Comment: thanks sean!! But I wanted opinion more on REBASS/ earlier(grid-styled) library, which promotes use of object literals to pass properties inside render function [link](https://github.com/rebassjs/rebass) .

Comment: You can also use the grid too.
For example, if you want use directly, 

`<YorApp  style={{display: "grid", gridTemplateArea: "1fr 1fr}/>`
className, and style are different expressing the style.
so, if you want detach the file, use the className.
else use the style.
i hope to this answer helpful to you~!